# how to get json object from html to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

This is my html file in spring mvc broadleaf, I am want to add pagination in that. I created and access the one object with the name of json.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bServerSide": false,
    "sort": "position",
    "sAjaxSource": "${json}",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "Business Name" },
        { "mData": "Business User Name" },
        { "mData": "Role" },
        { "mData": "Contact Email" },
        { "mData": "Contact Phone" },             
       ]
   } );
    } );

   </script>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="width_setter group" role="main">
    <div>
     <table id="example" class="display">
    <tr><td th:text="${json}">Business Name</td><td>Business User Name</td>                      
  <td>Role</td><td>Contact Mail</td><td>Contact Phone</td></tr>
</table></div>
    </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

The json object having the following values,

```
{
"modelList": [],
"iTotalRecords": 60,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 60,
"aaData": [
    {
        "address": "Admin Master Access",
        "organizationName": "ParkAvenue",
        "organizationId": 475,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Administrator",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "femina@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "044265612",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenadmin",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin",
        "shopOwnerUserId": -1,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "organizationName": "Femina1",
        "organizationId": 486,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "FeminaUser",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "femina1@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "1231231",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "femina1",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "femina1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1150,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "organizationName": "Acumen",
        "organizationId": 5,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "administrator",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenadmin",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "femina1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1200,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Femina2",
        "organizationId": 496,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "FeminaUser3",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "femina2@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "04423456",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "femina3",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "femina3",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1250,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Admin Master Access",
        "organizationName": "Femina2",
        "organizationId": 496,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Administrator",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "femina2@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "04423456",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenadmin",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin",
        "shopOwnerUserId": -1,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "ParkAvenue",
        "organizationId": 475,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "femina4",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "femina@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "044265612",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "femina4",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "femina4",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1350,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Porsche",
        "organizationId": 466,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "porsche5050",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "porsche@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "221212",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "porsche",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "tested",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1050,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Samson",
        "organizationId": 546,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Femina-Pradeep",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "samsung@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123465",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "feminaPradeep",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "feminaPradeep",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1450,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Samson Lighting",
        "organizationId": 554,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Xavier Pradep",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "samson@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "12345657",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenlb4d",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1500,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Rani Mahal",
        "organizationId": 564,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Rani",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "ranimagal@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123456789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenrani",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1550,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal Egmore",
        "organizationId": 574,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Kusal Egm",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalegmore@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenkusalegm",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1551,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Kusal ECR",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenkusalecr",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1552,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Groupm",
        "organizationId": 693,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Groupm",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "subbu@highpowerv.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "04445542000",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "groupm",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "groupm",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1600,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Acumen",
        "organizationId": 5,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "MuruganV",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "murugan",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "murugan",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1650,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Acumen",
        "organizationId": 5,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "MuruganvvV",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "muruganvv",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "murugan",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1652,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "pvr",
        "organizationId": 705,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "PVR",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "pvr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenpvr",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "acumenpvr",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1700,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Testing",
        "organizationId": 722,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "TESTing Demo",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "testing@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenTESTing",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "acumenTESTing",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1701,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal Shop Ecr",
        "organizationId": 771,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Kusal Shop ECR",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalflora@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "04424490200",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "kusalecr",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "kusalecr",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1705,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Acumen",
        "organizationId": 5,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "MuruganTEST",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "muruganTEST",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "murugan",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1706,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Admin Master Access",
        "organizationName": "Hyundai",
        "organizationId": 921,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Administrator",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "pavan.acumen@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "1231231231",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenadmin",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin",
        "shopOwnerUserId": -1,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Admin Master Access",
        "organizationName": "Business Testing",
        "organizationId": 929,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Administrator",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "pavan@acumentec.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123456",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenadmin",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin",
        "shopOwnerUserId": -1,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Ananda Bhavan",
        "organizationId": 781,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Ananda Bhavan",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "bhavan@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "04442333333",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "anandabhavan",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "anandabhavan",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1707,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal Shop Egmore",
        "organizationId": 791,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "kusal Shop Egmore",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalflora@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "04428193372",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "kusalegmore",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "kusalegmore",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1708,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Rani Marriage Hall",
        "organizationId": 801,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Rani Mahal",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "ranihall@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "0442599090",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "ranimahal",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "ranimahal",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1709,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Samson Lighting Pvt Ltd",
        "organizationId": 811,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Samson",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "sales@samsonlighting.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "04426671125",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "samson",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "samson",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1710,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "google tech",
        "organizationId": 825,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Google",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "pradeepj.acumen@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123456789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "googleuser",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "googleuser",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1750,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "google tech hyd",
        "organizationId": 833,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Google",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "pradeep@acumentec.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "125474545",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "googleuser",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "googleuser",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1750,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Propel Fitness",
        "organizationId": 908,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "acumenpropel",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "etst@tert.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "3234324",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenpropel",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1800,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Propel Fitness",
        "organizationId": 855,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "acumenpropel",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "test@test.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "04428261222",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenpropel",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1800,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Hyundai",
        "organizationId": 921,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Pavan",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "pavan.acumen@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "1231231231",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "hyundai",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "hyundai",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1850,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Acumen",
        "organizationId": 5,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "asdfghjkl",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pavan",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pavan",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1903,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Tyre Store",
        "organizationId": 983,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Pavan",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "pavan.acumen@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "8754566199",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "tyrestorechennai",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "tyrestorechennai",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1950,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Mokaba",
        "organizationId": 1002,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "acumenmokaba",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "pradeep@acumentec.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123456",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenmokaba",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "acumenmokaba",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2000,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Mokaba Chennai",
        "organizationId": 1018,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "acumenmokabauser",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "sdfgs@sfg.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "2343422",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenmokabauser",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "acumenmokabauser",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2050,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Mani Shop",
        "organizationId": 2500,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Manikandan",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "mani@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "044630630",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "mani",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "mani",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2150,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "kusal vadapalani",
        "organizationId": 2549,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "Kusal ECR",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "test@test.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "56546546",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "acumenkusalecr",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "admin1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1552,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "kusal vadapalani",
        "organizationId": 2549,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "asdfghjkl",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "test@test.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "56546546",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pavan",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pavan",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 1903,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeep",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeeptest",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pradeeptest",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2200,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeeptest",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeeptest1",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pradeeptest1",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2201,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeeptest2",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeeptest2",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pradeeptest2",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2250,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "sdfgfds",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "sdfgfds",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "sdfgfds",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2300,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeepj",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeepj",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pradeepj",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2301,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "ws",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "ws",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "ws",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2302,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeeptest123",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeeptest123",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pradeeptest123",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2303,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "kusal vadapalani",
        "organizationId": 2549,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "rade",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "test@test.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "56546546",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "rade",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "rade",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2304,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Kusal ECR",
        "organizationId": 584,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeeptesting",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "kusalecr@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123654789",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeeptesting",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pradeeptesting",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2350,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "kusal vadapalani",
        "organizationId": 2549,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeep12434",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "test@test.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "56546546",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeep12434",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "pradeep12434",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2400,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "woodlands10",
        "organizationId": 3249,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeepmac1",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "sdfg@sdfdfg.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "435345",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeepmac",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "acumen",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2100,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "woodlands",
        "organizationId": 3231,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeepmac1",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "sdf@sdf.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "123",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeepmac",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "acumen",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2100,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Shop Owner",
        "organizationName": "Pradeep T",
        "organizationId": 3356,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "pradeepmac1",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "test@test.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "3424324",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "pradeepmac",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "acumen",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2100,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Partner",
        "organizationName": "xxxxxx",
        "organizationId": 3431,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "venkat",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "venkadachalam.acumen@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "044630630",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "venkat",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "venkat",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2500,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    },
    {
        "address": "Partner",
        "organizationName": "xperia",
        "organizationId": 3453,
        "modelList": [],
        "shopOwnerName": "xperia.partnar",
        "shopOwnerEmail": "venkadachalam.acumen@gmail.com",
        "shopOwnerPhone": "044630630",
        "shopOwnerLogin": "xperia.partnar",
        "shopOwnerPassword": "xperia.partnar",
        "shopOwnerUserId": 2550,
        "iTotalRecords": 0,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 0
    }
]
}
```

How to add this to the javascript file and create pagination with sorting and searching options.

Comment: Try using JSON.parse

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `selector` as follow to get the value of `tr`'s attribute. And parse it into `JSON`

```
var myJson = JSON.parse($('td[th\\:text]').attr('th\\:text'));
```

Comment: How to add it in the sAjaxsource